# Active admin un-implemented actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I receive the following error:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /add_comment/9

Here is the root of this error:

```
# By default Rails will render un-implemented actions when the view exists. Becuase Active
# Admin allows you to not render any of the actions by using the #actions method, we need
# to check if they are implemented.

def only_render_implemented_actions
  raise AbstractController::ActionNotFound unless action_methods.include?(params[:action])
end
```

**I did not have this error before bundling active admin.**

My add_comment action is inside my comments controller with the following route:

```
match 'add_comment/:id', to: 'comments#new'
```

I have uninstalled active admin, and confirmed that active admin was causing the issue.

Does anyone know what this is about?

Comment: I'm not sure how the snippet you posted could be any clearer. Perhaps you have not implemented the action? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, I couldn't really even phrase the question, because I just have no idea what I'm dealing with. Do I need to add something special for an un-implemented action, whatever that is?

Comment: Where is your `add_comment` action defined?

Comment: match 'add_comment/:id', to: 'comments#new' (in my comments controller under 'new') .. Do you think it's the way I've defined my route?

Comment: Try redefining the `only_render_implemented_actions` method in your CommentsController to just do nothing. It's possible it's trying to find a method called `add_comment` and raising an error because your method is actually called `new`.

Comment: How exactly would you suggest doing that? I mean, what should I put into the model exactly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37616/discussion-between-zach-kemp-and-abram)

Answer (score 0):

I received some help from the github issue tracker for Active Admin. My dilemma was resolved by changing to AdminComment in the initializer.

> Active Admin comes with a commenting system built-in, and your routes
>   seem to be conflicting... Which is weird, because the route you
>   mentioned is in the root namespace but you have Active Admin
>   configured for the (default) admin namespace.
>
> Can you try using the latest code on master, and setting this in the
>   initializer?

```
config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment' # Defaults to 'Comment'
```

> Alternatively, you could disable comments entirely:

```
config.show_comments_in_menu      = false          # Defaults to true
```